# AppEngine Endpoint - header data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using Google App Engine's Endpoint. How can I get built-in AppEngine's header such as

```
X-AppEngine-Country
X-AppEngine-Region
X-AppEngine-City
X-AppEngine-CityLatLong
```

If I use Servlet, it's easy to obtain by

```
request.getHeader("...")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solutio, add an HttpServletRequest parameter to your endpoint method, e.g.

```
@ApiMethod
public MyResponse getResponse( HttpServletRequest req, @Named("infoId") String infoId ) {
    // Use 'req' as you would in a servlet, e.g.
    String countryCode = req.getHeader("X-AppEngine-Country");
}
```

Comment: Looks good, hope you'll accept your own answer when the time-out period needed for that elapses!-)